# Can I hide the warning message "DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle" in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

The import instruction `require "Win32API"` throws this warning message at execution time:

> DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle

It is very annonying to see that message every time that the script is ran, I'm just requiring `DL` to launch a Win32 MessageBox, so really does not matter whether it is considered deprecated or not, it does not need a refactor at all for only one MessageBox.

Then, can I do something to hide that warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit `<Ruby_Install_Dir>\lib\ruby\<VERSION>\Win32API.rb`, delete the `warn` line in the file.

For my installation, the file locates in `C:\Ruby23-x64\lib\ruby\2.3.0\Win32API.rb` and the warning line is like

```
warn "Warning:#{caller[0].sub(/:in `.*'\z/, '')}: Win32API is deprecated after Ruby 1.9.1; use fiddle directly instead" if $VERBOSE
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but I was expecting a solution that implies editing the script file itself, not editing the Ruby's installation files, the reason is because the script will be executed on other machines so I cannot demand they to do manual modifications on the file you mentioned...

Comment: Anyways I found the solution before receiving your answer, simply with: `original_verbose, $VERBOSE = $VERBOSE, nil` and restore the verbosity with `$VERBOSE = $VERBOSE`

Comment: @ElektroStudios yes, that's controlled by the suffix condition `if $VERBOSE`